# haproxy match various conditions in use_backend

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I'm trying to match various conditions inside one backend, like this:

```
acl rule1 hdr_dom(host) -i ext1
acl rule2 utl_beg /img
default_backend back-server-http if rule1 and rule2
```

but, how can I put this "and" between the two rules?

Comment: An other related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/768575/haproxy-acl-multiple-or-conditions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, this is the solution:

```
acl rule1  hdr_dom(host) -i www.uno.es  hdr_dom(host) -i www.one.com
use_backend uno.com if rule1
```

Comment: How can a request have both hosts?  It seems impossible that this ACL could ever be matched.

Comment: Yes, you can, its the same if you add contidions to the same acl inside different lines.

Comment: the answer example doesn't match the question example: for the question would it be something like this: `acl rule1 hdr_dom(host) -i ext1 utl_beg /img`?

Comment: @Thayne - see the examples here: https://github.com/langpavel/haproxy-doc/blob/master/version-1-4-19/tex/gen_07-07--using-acls-to-form-conditions.tex. Given what you've written I'd expect that to work.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need to use the word "and" between the two rules. It's implicit.

Source: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt in  *Section 7.2*

Answer (score -1):

I think the below syntax will do the trick (check this link [HAProxy - basic authentication for backend server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869330/haproxy-basic-authentication-for-backend-server/64138986#64138986))

```
acl rule1 hdr_dom(host) -i ext1
acl rule2 utl_beg /img
default_backend back-server-http if rule1  rule2
```

Comment: 'default_backend' cannot handle unexpected argument 'if'.